# Exactly align picture to heading text

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

After trying a lot of suggestions on how to solve the following problem, I think it is time to ask for direct help.

I am trying to exactly align a logo (picture) to its following text (heading). All the solutions I tried before have shown an asymmetrical placement (cp. attached picture).

I hope somebody can help me on this. Thank you!

[My actual output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVs9R.png)

I want to have both red line segments of the same length, in other words: center the text relative to the picture.

And here is a code snippet:

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="~/Content/images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="50" height="50"/>
    <h2 style="display:inline">Tool XY</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First method**

Add `vertical-align:middle;margin:0;` to **h2**

```
.jumbotron h2, .jumbotron img{
  display: inline;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0;
}
```

```css
.jumbotron img, .jumbotron h2{
  display: inline;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2I5h.png" alt="logo" width="50" height="50"/>
  <h2 style="">Tool XY</h2>
</div>
```

**Second Method**

Add to this style to **jumbotron**

```
.jumbotron{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.jumbotron{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2I5h.png" alt="logo" width="50" height="50"/>
  <h2>Tool XY</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay I'm confused. This example looks perfect in the implemented Run code snippet of stackoverflow, but still in my case it does not. Is there probably something else going wrong?

Comment: Can you add to both **image** and **h2** this style?

Comment: To add **margin:0;** to `h2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-align: middle;` in img tag to vertical center text

```css
.jumbotron img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="logo" width="50" height="50"/>
    <h2 style="display:inline">Tool XY</h2>
</div>
```